# How to use sessions in PHP with Login Form

Tags: php, mysql, session

Currently trying to develop on a login/dashboard which a friend of mine started. I'm struggling with sessions. I want when the User is not logged in and they try to visit /dashboard.php, it will redirect them to login.php so they have to login if you know what i mean:

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
isset($_SESSION['id']);

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

function Register()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gtaauth");
if(!empty($_POST['Key']) AND !empty($_POST['Username']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.php, is it empty or have some text
{   
    $errors="";
    $query="SELECT `Key` FROM `Keys` WHERE `Key`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($row['Key'])
    {
        $query="SELECT `Activated` FROM `Keys` WHERE `Key`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       if($row['Activated']){
        $errors= "This key has already been activated. You cannot create an account with this key.";

       }

    }
    else{
        $errors= "Key not found. Please contact us for assistance!";   
    }
    if($errors){
        echo $errors;
    }else{
        //ip insert update
            $query="UPDATE `Keys` SET `IP` = '$IP', `Activated` = '1', `Username` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."' WHERE `Key`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            if($result){
                $query="UPDATE `Keys` SET `Timestamp` = NOW(), `IP` = '$IP', `DATE` = NOW() WHERE `Keys`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }else{
                $errors.="Could not sign up. Please contact us for assistance.";
            }
        //email check 
            $query = "SELECT*FROM `Users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Email'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($results>0){
                $errors.="The email provided is already registered. </br>";
            }
        //username check
            $query = "SELECT*FROM `Users` WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($results>0){
                $errors.= "The username provided is already registered. </nr>";
            }

            if($errors){
              echo $errors;
            }else{
                $query = "INSERT INTO `Users` (`username`,`name`,`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Username'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['Email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                if($result){
                                  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function () { alert("Registration and activation was successful."); } </script>';

                    }else{
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function () { alert("An error occurred. Please contact us for assistance."); } </script>';
                       // echo"Error Please contact me or jelly (skype: mathiis95)";
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

 function SignIn(){

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gtaauth");

        $query = "SELECT `email` FROM `Users` WHERE `username`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if($row['email']){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."' AND `password`= '".md5(md5($row['email']).$_POST['password'])."'";     
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `Keys` WHERE `Username`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."'";     
            $result1=mysqli_query($con,$query1);
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

            if($row){    
                if(!empty($row['password']) AND !empty($row['username']))
                {
                     $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                     $_SESSION['isstaff']=$row['isStaff'];
                     $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
                     $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
                     $_SESSION['key']=$row1['Key'];
                     $_SESSION['date']=$row1['DATE'];
                     $_SESSION['ip']=$row1['IP'];
                     header("Location: dashboard.php");
                }else{
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function () { alert("Incorrect email or password."); } </script>';
                    //echo "Incorrect Email Or Password";
              }
           }
        }
    }

if(isset($_POST['licence']))
{
    Register();
}

if(isset($_POST['sign']))
{
   SignIn();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $isLogin = 1;
}else{
    $isLogin=0;
}
?>
---- html is here -----
```

dashboard.php (I only included the top PHP as there is no other PHP on this page except for echoing the Username so it will display it when they login):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location:login.php");
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the session values are present or not in `dashboard.php`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['ip'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
```